# Increase index in for loop

Tags: python

I need to calculate the B columns and I wanted to do that using a for loop.  It's calculation is a a static column (Col2) multiplied by the previous column (A) while also adding in the B column.
[Intended Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrvid.png)

```
for i in range(df.shape[1], 3, -1):
    bcol = (df['Col2']*df.iloc[:,i]).round(decimals=1)
    df.insert(i, 'B', bcol, allow_duplicates=True)
```

Error I get: "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: It's common when using a backwards range to forget that it will start with the starting number.  If `df.shape[1]` is 9, then `i` will start at 9, but the valid indexes are only 0 through 8.  Add a `-1` there.

Comment: You need to stay within the dimension of the dataset [`Read this`](https://researchdatapod.com/indexerror-single-positional-indexer-is-out-of-bounds/#:~:text=The%20error%20%E2%80%9CIndexerror%3A%20single%20positional,of%20a%20dataset%20using%20shape.)

Comment: df.iloc[:,-1]??? Close, no error, but now I can't tell what's its calculating. The number is very off. I just need it to pick up the previous column to B.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the column name by using f-strings and iterate through them using for loop like below:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'col2':[1,2,3],'A1':[4,5,6],'B1':[None,None,None],'A2':[5,6,7],'B2':[None,None,None]})

for i in range(1,3,1):
  x[f'B{i}'] = (x['col2'] * x[f'A{i}']).round(decimals=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help your answer?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(1,5):
    print (f"Index{i-1} - Index{i} = {arr[i] - arr[i-1]}"
```

You can use this logic for 2-D matrix also by iterating all the values in column then iterate over rows